# Powershell progress bar when using get-adcomputer

Tags: powershell

So I'm new to Powershell as such I imagine that I am missing something stupid simple.

I am trying to get a progress bar to display showing how long my script listed below is going to take to display all *ActiveDirectory* computers with x,y,z properties.

I understand that to get a progress bar you need a loop but I am not sure if I'm actually accomplishing that. Nothing seems to happen when I execute the command

```
$computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem
foreach ($computer in $computerList) {
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing computers' -CurrentOperation $computer
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
}
```

Comment: For progress you also need the PercentComplete parameter.  Otherwise you'll get only a status message. Have a look at `man write-progress -ex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides missing the PercentComplete parameter that others have pointed out, your first line is going to complete, before your `foreach` loop starts. So your `Write-Progress` is just going to go off show the length of time of your `sleep`. Not how long it takes to display those properties from the first line.

If your plan is to do something with that data in place of `Sleep` then it would make sense. Otherwise the processing is already done, before you start tracking progress.

If you wanted to know how long the command takes afterwards, then you want to use `Measure-Command`

```
Measure-Command {Get-ADComputer -filter * -Property * | select Name,OperatingSystem}
```

If you wanted to track the progress of that command in the pipeline as it's executing, you are going to run into a couple issues. First the server doesn't tell you how many objects it has. But say you ran it before and knew how many objects were returned, you could do something like this:

```
$i = 0
Get-ADComputer -filter * -Property * | 
    % { 
        $i++
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing computers' -PercentComplete ($i/$PreviousCount*100)
    } | 
    Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem
```

Second doing this is doing to add a lot of overhead making your command take significantly longer.

Another recommendation, since you are filtering off everything with `Select-Object` and care how long the operation takes, only request those two properties.

```
$computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property Name,OperatingSystem | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem
```

Comment: Hey man thanks, that was a great post and easy to understand. I would like to give you a few points how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need `-PercentComplete $Progress` to show the Progress!

Here is an implementation with your example:

```
$computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,OperatingSystem
$i=0
foreach ($computer in $computerList) {
    $Progress = $i/$computerList.count*100
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing computers' -CurrentOperation $computer -PercentComplete $Progress
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200;$i++
}
```

Comment: just got the following error: Get-ADComputer : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
At line:1 char:17
+ $computerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name,Operat ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

Comment: @cmoneyg This error is unrelated to the `foreach` loop. You should troubleshoot your `Get-ADComputer` command.

Comment: You are correct @sodawillow here is a good article on it. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx